# How to skip a field when AutoFiltering via VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, criteria, autofilter

I have a filter procedure with which I want to **skip filtering certain columns** if it doesn't contain relevant data. This is my code followed by my description and question:

```
Sub FilterData()

    'First I select my values in a pivot table in my Dashboard sheet. 
    '  Cell references P7, P8 and P9 are fields in this pivot;
    Myvalue1 = Sheets("Dashboard").Range("P7")
    Myvalue2 = Sheets("Dashboard").Range("P8")
    Myvalue3 = Sheets("Dashboard").Range("P9")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Next I go to my dataset that the pivot is based upon in another sheet 
    '  to filter the data according to my selected values from before.
    Sheets("Data").Visible = True
    Sheets("Data").Select

    'First I clear existing filters if applicable, then I start to sort the data.
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BR$30000").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=Myvalue1
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BR$30000").AutoFilter Field:=66, Criteria1:=Myvalue2
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BR$30000").AutoFilter Field:=67, Criteria1:=Myvalue3
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**Remarks:**
Now my sheet named `Data` will display the extract I want, based on my selection in the pivot.  However, if I do **not** make a selection in, for example, `P7` (thus the PivotTable shows *(All)* in cell P7) then everything is filtered away and there is no data to display.

The reason I want to filter my raw data rather than double-click the pivot to see the detailed data, is because I want to be able to edit the data I select and save the changes afterwards.

**Question:**
How do I tell my code to **leave `Column 12` (`Myvalue1`) unfiltered if the value of `Cell P7` is `(All)`?**

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [so]!  It would be helpful if you could include a screen show showing an example of your data, as well as the problem - and here are tips on how to create a **[mcve]**.   Also, be sure to check out the [tour] (you'll earn your first badge!), as well as [ask].

Comment: Just guessing without seeing your data but what about a simple `If` statement (much like the one you're already using) something like `If P7<>"(All)" Then ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BR$30000").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=Myvalue1`

Comment: You've answered your own question :) If Range("P7") = "(All)" Then dontdostuff End If. Or more realistically If Range("P7") <> "(All)" Then dodostuff End If

Comment: Issue Solved! Thanks to ashleedawg and Absinthe for the input. This is what I ended up with: If Myvalue1 <> "(All)" Then
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BR$30000").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:= _
Myvalue1
End If